# How do I clear the Shopify cart whenever the homepage is loaded?

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify

I am a designer and have been asked by a client if I can help them with a certain piece of functionality on their store.

They are only selling one type of product on their store, with different bundle options available. Since customers will only ever be purchasing 1 product at any given time from the store, they have asked me if I can have it so that only 1 product can be in the cart at any given time, and if the customer were to go back from the checkout page (or any other page) and select a different bundle of the product, it would remove the other product from their cart.

I don't have any AJAX cart items (drawers, slideout cart etc) on the site so using AJAX would be an option here. My knowledge of anything other than HTML, CSS and some basic JS is very limited.

With my limited knowledge, I was thinking that running a script that clears the cart when the Homepage is loaded would work well, as there are really only 3 pages on the site, the Homepage, Cart page and Checkout page. This is code that I found, but I am not sure how to implement it or if it would even work at all:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clear-cart').on('load',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/cart/clear.js',
      success: function(){
        alert('I cleared the cart!');
      },
      dataType: 'json'
    });
  })
});
```

Your effort to help out this noob in need would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the class of the page like on the default debut theme it uses the class `template-index` for the index page aka homepage.
[image]

and add the condition into the code to check it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('load',function(e){
    if( !$('body').hasClass('template-index') ){
       return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/cart/clear.js',
      success: function(){
        alert('I cleared the cart!');
      },
      dataType: 'json'
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, and where about would I place this code within the theme files?

Comment: add the code at end of `theme.liquid` in `<script></script>` tag before the `</body>` tag